# Hypothetical Phrases that are somehow "Restricted"

Tags: verbs

In my Italian textbook, there’s an explanation that I’m having trouble understanding:

> Quando il periodo ipotetico ha valore limitativo, la frase introdotta 
>       dal ‘se’ può essere espressa attraverso ‘a + infinito’. Questa 
>       struttura è più frequente nelle ipotetiche che usano il modo indicativo.

And then some examples are presented:

> A saperlo prima, mi comportavo diversamente.
>       A essere sincero, non so niente di questo.
>       A pensar male, spesso si indovina la verità.
>       A essere corretti, dovremmo smettere di aiutarlo.

Before this, the book explained how you can use the gerund in these types of sentences by providing a “before and after”. This construction made sense, because I understood the rule and what’s being “replaced.” Could someone show me what’s being replaced, and what “limitative” means in this context? This is what I mean:

> Potendo vengo a trovarvi. = Se (io) posso, (io) vengo a trovarvi.
>       Volendo potresti aiutarmi. = Se (tu) volessi, (tu) potresti aiutarmi.
>        -- If subject in both clauses is same, you can use the gerund of the verb instead.

Comment: It's what is called a "forma implicita della proposizione condizionale", that is, an "implicit form of a conditional clause". I think it corresponds to a condition expressed in an impersonal way (for instance, "A pensar male, spesso si indovina la verità" = "Se si pensa male, spesso si indovina la verità") or to a conditional proposition which a subject that it's the same of that of the main clause (for instance, "A essere sincero, non so niente di questo" = "Se sono sincero, non so niente di questo").

Answer (score 2):

**Limitative sentences** talk about an action or event that *will/will not* take place unless something happens.

These clause are almost always in the indicative and are introduced by **«purché, sempreché, solo che, per poco che, a condizione che, a patto che», etc.**

**"Quando il periodo ipotetico ha valore limitativo"** means *"when the conditional sentence can be expresed as a limitative sentence"*, that is it can be expressed with the aid of prepositions «purché, sempreché, solo che, per poco che, a condizione che, a patto che», etc.

So, in these cases, instead of using a ***se*** clause, one can express a condition by using one of the following verb forms: *gerund, infinitive or participle*.

### Gerund

> **Andando in treno** (= *se andassimo* in treno, *purché si vada*, *a condizione che si vada*,...), **si risparmierebbe un’ora.**
> *If we (one) went by train, we (one) would save an hour.*

Even when referring to a past context, only the present gerund can be used:

> **Guidando con più prudenza** (= *se avessi guidato* con più prudenza, *sempreché avessi guidato*, *purché avessi guidato*,...), **non avresti preso la multa.**
> *If you had driven more carefully, you wouldn’t have got a fine.*

### Past participle

**With "se"**

> **Se compilato con attenzione** (= *se viene compilato* con attenzione, *purché venga compilato*, *a condizione che venga compilato*,...), **il questionario può essere uno strumento utile per capire il carattere di una persona.**
> *If compiled with care, the questionnaire can be a useful tool to understand
> someone’s character.*

**Without "se"**

> **Fatto in modo incompleto** (= *se fosse fatto* in modo incompleto, *nel caso che fosse fatto*, *nella condizione che fosse fatto*,...), **il sondaggio non sarebbe molto valido.**
> *(If it were) done in an incomplete fashion, the survey wouldn’t be very valid.*

### Infinitive

> **A guardarla bene** (= *se la si guarda bene*, *sempreché la si gardi bene*, *purché la si guardi bene*,...), **sembra più vecchia di lui.**
> *If you look at her closely, she seems older than him.*
>
> **A reagire in modo eccessivo** (= *se reagisci* in modo eccessivo, *sempreché reagisci*,...), **, rischi di allontanare tuo figlio.**
> *If you overreact, you risk alienating your son.*

You can easily analyse [your sentences](https://www.almaedizioni.it/media/upload/anteprime/gps2_cap9_frasi_ipotetiche.pdf) in the same way.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, a limitative sentence is something like "Se ti chiamassi, te lo spiegherei." and not "Se fossi un animale, mangerei più carne." Right?

Comment: @Marco: I'm not sure about that because I would paraphrase your first example as "Se l'avessi saputo prima, mi sarei comportato diversamente.